# How to interpret the cross-spectral density of an incoherent field

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, imaging

I have been given a definition of the cross spectral density of a completely incoherent field:

$$W(x_1,x_2)=S_0\delta(x_1-x_2)$$

How do I interpret this? As I understand it, this means that there are only correlations when $x_1=x_2$ (i.e. when both points are the same), so it is completely incoherent. However, I'm not sure what the significance of $S_0$ is. What is its physical interpretation and how could I determine its value?